# Google maps, insert pin based on input and make it draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So I have a map and a form, once user fills in address + postcode it puts a marker to the map, however I want to make it draggable and keep a value of lat and long.

For some reason, I cannot move the marker why?

JS:

```
function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 8,
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644}
        });
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        document.getElementById('postcode').addEventListener('blur', function() {

          geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
        });
      }

      function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
        var address = document.getElementById('address2').value +','+ document.getElementById('postcode').value;
        console.log(address);
        geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: resultsMap,
              position: results[0].geometry.location,
              title: address,
              draggable:true,
            });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(marker){
        var latLng = marker.latLng; 
        currentLatitude = latLng.lat();
        currentLongitude = latLng.lng();
        jQ("#latitude").val(currentLatitude);
        jQ("#longitude").val(currentLongitude);
                });
          } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
```

Comment: I answered a question that is pretty similar, I think.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44030800/google-places-api-with-search-engine-and-draggable-marker-and-that-puts-coordina/44080553#44080553

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare the var  map  at window level

```
var map;

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
.....
```

then in you geocodeAddress function you should refer to map for marker map

```
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location,
          title: address,
          draggable:true,
        });
```

*looking to your code the marker don't should be placed on map because you refer resultsMap*

Comment: This is  a new question or i don't understand your orginal question ???'  .. your original question seems related to the fact you don't move a marker  .. and my answer i think should resolve the question ..

Comment: sorry my bad, was thinking about something else, if you add a new marker can you take it's long and lat even if it is not dragged?

Comment: yes ..but please  ... post a new question for this and eventually comment me the new  link  .. and rate my asnwer  as right too

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44701450/google-maps-api-get-lat-and-lng-and-replace-marker new link ;)  @scaisedge